# htaccess rewrite rule not firing on mobile devices - whats wrong with my regex?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

At the very top of my .htaccess file I have:

```
`# BEGIN Random redirect Fedbackurl
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.example.com/feedback/?.$ /random.php [L]
# END Random redirect Feedbackurl`
```

The idea is to send any requests to example.com/feedback (and any trailing parameters) onto the random.php file, which will do a bit of calculation and send the visitor onto a new url.

The code works fine on desktop.

But on mobil devices, it just lands on example.com/feedback/ (no redirection is taken place).

Random.php file:
`<?php $random = rand(1,17); $query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; header("Location: https://example.com/feedbackformular?sp=".$random."&".$query); exit(); ?>`

I tried to move the .htaccess code all the way up, since I thought that it didn't fire because of other stuff in the .htaccss

Comment: What is the actual URL you are requesting? Can't see `^.example.com/feedback/?.$` making much sense.

Comment: I can't share the real domain :(

Comment: Then give a generic example of the full, absolute URL at least. Right now, I can't tell for sure if `example.com/feedback` means something like `https://example.com/feedback` - or something like `https://somedomain.xyz/example.com/feedback`. The latter is of course less likely - but since that corresponds to the path you tried to match with your rule, this needs clarification first. (You are aware that RewriteRule matches against the path component of the URL only, are you not ...?)

Answer (score 0):

You tried to guess how a `RewriteRule` works, how you can implement it. But you guessed wrong. It really would make sense for you to take a look into the documentation. It is of excellent quality, somes with good examples. You will learn a lot and be able to implement your own solutions after having understood how that technology actually works.

I doubt very much that the implementation you posted does anything that makes sense. You state "The code works fine on desktop.", but I don't see how that can actually be the case.

Here is a variant of your attempted rule which should work, as far as we can say by the vague description you gave in your question:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?feedback/?$ /random.php [L]
```

Here is the documentation of the apache rewrite module which you are using here:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html